# Calculating angle of human joint beyond 180° in 3D

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, 3d

I'm having some trouble calculating the angle of an human joint in 3D using the Microsoft Kinect.

Here's an example of the angle of the elbow (using the shoulder and wrist joint):

[Image of example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tkQp.jpg)

Calculating angles between 0° and 180° is no problem, but when the person **hyper**extends his elbow my calculation returns 170° instead of 190°.

The calculation I'm using is as follows:

1. $d = b - a$
2. $e = b - c$

Where a, b and c are 3D-points and d and e are 3D-vectors.

My question is: **How can I calculate the angle between $d$ en $e$ where the angle is between 0° and 360°?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly are $a, b, c, d$ and $e$?

Comment: @Daan Michiels: $a$, $b$ and $c$ are 3D-points. $d$ and $e$ are 3D-vectors.

Comment: I am doing the same task, can you provide some example project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about implementing an algorithm to detect if the elbow is hyper-extending? If it is, then change the angle x into a reflex angle 360-x.

This algorithm would work by extending the line segment AB far enough to cover the x-position of C. Call D the point on AB with the same x-position as C. Then just compare the y-position of C and D to find out if the elbow is indeed hyper-extending.

Comment: I think this might work. I'm going to try it out and let you know!